# latest integration services for Hyper-v host

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2012

I have Hyper-V hosts with both Win Server 2008 R2 and Win Server 2012. These hosts are not connected on the internet and do get security patches installed every month.

How do I know if the integration services present on a Hyper-v host are the latest?

How do I update the integration services to the latest version if I ever found that the integration services on a particular hyper-v host are not the latest ?